# What should you do in cases where you've got answers, but others think that the question is not a challenge?

Tags: discussion, policy, challenges, new-users

See, for example, a question I asked earlier: [Write the shortest code to generate a random number between 1 and x](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/23497/write-the-shortest-code-to-generate-a-random-number-between-1-and-x).

@Oberon said *["I'm not a downvoter, but maybe it's because the question isn't much of a challenge."](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/23497/write-the-shortest-code-to-generate-a-random-number-between-1-and-x#comment48929_23497)*, and his comment has got 6 up-votes.

So what should you do, in cases like this? Should you vote to close your own question? Should you delete it outright?

Comment: One way is to delete the question and run it through the sandbox.

Comment: This question can't be saved: it's asking for a single library call in almost any language which meets the "two implementations" rule.

Comment: @Quincunx Um... How do I do that? What is the sandbox?

Comment: @Quincunx Is the sandbox the meta post called "Proposed questions sandbox - Mark X"?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I can't delete it. When I try, I get a message saying that the question has answers and can't be deleted. What should I do?

Comment: Well, that's when you flag the post for moderator deletion. :-) (I've taken care of it now.)

Comment: @toothbrush Yes, that is the sandbox.